# MySQL (MyISAM) SELECT query takes too long with join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, query-performance

I have a pretty long insert query that inserts data from a select query in a table. The problem is that the select query takes too long to execute. The table is MyISAM and the select locks the table which affects other users who also use the table. I have found that problem of the query is a join.

When I remove this part of the query, it takes less then a second to execute but when I leave this part the query takes more than 15 minutes:

```
LEFT JOIN enq_217 Pex_217 
    ON e.survey_panelId = Pex_217.survey_panelId 
    AND e.survey_respondentId = Pex_217.survey_respondentId 
    AND Pex_217.survey_respondentId != 0
```

`db.table_1` contains 5,90,145 rows and `e` contains 4,703 rows.

Explain Output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY e   ALL survey_endTime,survey_type  NULL    NULL    NULL    4703    Using where
1   PRIMARY Pex_217 ref survey_respondentId,idx_table_1 idx_table_1 8   e.survey_panelId,e.survey_respondentId  2   Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  enq_11525_timing    eq_ref  code    code    80  e.code  1
```

How can I edit this part of the query to be faster?

Comment: can you show output of `EXPLAIN`

Comment: The total query is 16610 characters long..

Comment: Run query using `Explain your query` and show the output

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KspHen6J

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  `LEFT JOIN enq_217 Pex_217 TB1 ` will generate an error.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating an index on the table `db.table_1` for the fields `panelId` and `respondentId`

Comment: After adding an index the query is still extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

You want an index on the table.  The best index for this logic is:

```
create index idx_table_1 on table_1(panelId, respondentId)
```

The order of these two columns in the index should not matter.

You might want to include other columns in the index, depending on what the rest of the query is doing.

Note:  a single index with both columns is different from two indexes with each column.

Comment: I used your query but the select query still takes too long to execute and it will hold up all the other users on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a `LEFT` join?

How many rows in `Pex_217`?

Run `ANALYZE TABLE` on each table used.  (This *sometimes* helps MyISAM; rarely is needed for InnoDB.)

Since the 'real problem' seems to be that the query "holds up other users", switch to InnoDB.

[*Tips on conversion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

The `JOIN` is not that bad (with the new index -- note `Using index`):  4703 rows scanned, then reach into the other table's index about 2 times each.

Perhaps the "Dependent subquery" is the costly part.  Let's see that.